# Неправильные данные в памяти

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

Нашел ошибку в коде и очень странно что она есть. Я указал на нее с помощью `< --`. дело в том, что я указал переменной `sizeof_s` размер 4 байта и число 16, что равно структуре `sockaddr_in`, но если в коде написать в той строке так `mov edx, [sizeof_s]` то запишется почему то перевернутый адрес порта, но почему?

**Вот код:**

```
;DEFAULT REL
global main
extern printf
extern inet_aton
extern perror
extern connect

section .text

shellcode:
    mov rax, 59
    mov rdi, [path]
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall

exploit:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, [sock]
    lea rsi, [shellcode]
    mov rdx, [size_of_shellcode]
    syscall
    ret
main:
;------ получаем сокет -------
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdi, rdi
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rdx, 0
    mov si, [SOCK_STREAM]
    mov di, [PF_INET]
    mov rax, 41
    syscall
    mov [sock], eax
    cmp rax, 0
    jg continue_socket
    xor rax, rax
    lea rdi, [cant_socket]
    syscall
    jmp exit
;---- заполнить структуру ----
continue_socket:
    xor rax, rax
    mov ax, [PF_INET]
    mov [s + sockaddr_in.family], ax
    mov ax, [server_port]
    xchg al, ah
    mov [s + sockaddr_in.port], ax
    xor rax, rax
    lea rdi, [host]
    xor rsi, rsi
    lea esi, [s + sockaddr_in.s_addr]
    call inet_aton
    cmp rax, 0
    jg continue_fill
    lea rdi, [cant_fill]
    call perror
    jmp exit
;------- подключение --------
continue_fill:
    xor rax, rax
    mov [s + sockaddr_in.data], rax
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdi, rdi
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov edx, 16        ; < ---------- вот здесь я присваивал [sizeof_s]
    lea rsi, [s]
    mov edi, [sock]
    xor rax, rax
    call connect
    cmp rax, 0
    je continue_connect
    lea rdi, [cant_connect]
    call perror
    jmp exit
continue_connect:
;---- написать сообщение ----
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, 1
    call exploit
;---- выход из программы ----
exit:
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
    ret


section .data
struc sockaddr_in
    .family  resw  1
    .port    resw  1
    .s_addr  resd  1
    .data    resb  8
endstruc
cant_socket   db    'Не удалось получить сокет', 0xa, 0x0
cant_fill     db    'Не удалось преобразовать ip', 0x0
cant_connect  db    'Невозможно подключиться', 0x0

host          db    '127.0.0.1', 0x0
path          dq    '/bin/sh'
size          dd    $ - path
sock          dd    0
s             istruc sockaddr_in 
sizeof_s      dd    16
server_port   dw    8020

PF_INET       dw    2
SOCK_STREAM   dw    1

size_of_shellcode dd exploit - shellcode
```

**И компиляция:**

```
all:
        nasm -f elf64 bf.asm -o bf.o
        gcc -no-pie bf.o -o test
#       ld -b elf64-x86-64 bf.o inet.o -lc -o test
```

Comment: потому что адрес порта записывается в сетевом порядке. А у Вас Litte Endian система (то есть, порядок обратный). Просто разверните.

Comment: Как определили, что у вас данные неправильные записываются?

Comment: @insolor я в отладчике смотрел. после того как присваивался `sizeof_s`, там было не 16 байт, а часть `server_port` и часть `PF_INET`. но почему так не понятно.

Comment: @KoVadim вы уверены, что посмотрели мой код? там же вот есть, перевод в сетевой порядок.`    mov ax, [server_port]
    xchg al, ah
    mov [s + sockaddr_in.port], ax`. короче посмотрите после метки continue_socket.

Comment: посмотрел, перечитал вопрос и теперь совсем не понимаю, что же не так и почему в вопросе говорится о записи размера.

Comment: @KoVadim посмотрите в секции data переменную sizeof_s. в нее я записываю 16. но в коде когда я хочу получить ее содержимое, она выдает [server_port} + [PF_INET].

Comment: Посмотрел под дизассемблером - у вас не создается структура, тупо метки s и sizeof_s совпадают в памяти. Нормально структуру создает, если использовать такой синтаксис: https://pastebin.com/p2ChxGAe Работает после исправления или нет - не проверял.

Comment: P.S. я предполагаю, что nasm считает, что все что идет ниже `s istruc sockaddr_in` - это часть этой структуры. Почему при этом не ругается на отсутствующий `iend` - не понятно. Но может так разработчиками задумано. Но в любом случае это объясняет почему из `sizeof_s` читается порт - в первое поле структуры перед этим его и записали, а первое поле структуры у вас пересекается с `s_size`.

Comment: @insolor ого. спасибо за этот момент. буду знать. я думал что если создать как я создавал, то это нормально, если не нужно данные записывать.

Answer (score 0):

Скомпилировал код из вопроса и посмотрел под дизассемблером, оказалось, что метки `s` и `sizeof_s` совпадают в памяти. Нормально структура создается, если использовать такой код:

```
s istruc sockaddr_in
    at sockaddr_in.family, dw 0
    at sockaddr_in.port,   dw 0
    at sockaddr_in.s_addr, dd 0
    at sockaddr_in.data,   db 0
iend
sizeof_s      dd    16
```

Документация: [ISTRUC, AT иIEND: Объявление экземпляров структур](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/nasm/nasm_ru4.html#section-4.7.4)

Я предполагаю, что nasm считает, что все что идет ниже `s istruc sockaddr_in` - это часть этой структуры. Почему при этом не ругается на отсутствующий `iend` - не понятно. Но может так разработчиками задумано. Но в любом случае это объясняет, почему из `sizeof_s` читается порт - в первое поле структуры перед этим его и записали, а первое поле структуры у вас пересекается с `s_size`.